# Being able to sort the most viewed questions in Stack Overflow for Teams

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow-for-teams, filtering

I think, it would be nice to see which questions are most consulted.

This would allow our team to:

1. Focus on issues that need improvement.
2. See what type of issue is most relevant to our team *(we also use Stack Overflow for the team as a wiki and it would help to see which document makes sense, and which does not)*.
3. See which question to prioritize.

Also, I like the upvote feature, but not everybody is using it. which make it hard to know which question have to be answered first. This may also be useful for the public Stack Overflow community.

**Edit: Explained use case**
I've a small team of 7 people, which contains front/backender, sales and support.
So, the question diverge at lot.

Front/backender know already a lot about stack overflow and have higher chance to upvote, but sales & support don't. Pushing them to learn stack overflow is already a challenge and forcing them to vote could be counterproductive.

But maybe sales & support are the one that view the most a lot of answers, while developer could be people that only have a look once a day.

In the case I will sort with `Most frequent` I may only see the developer questions & answers, which will ignore the rest of the team...

Answer (score 3):

The "frequent" sort option might give you an indication of questions that are regularly referenced - so questions that are linked to or have questions closed as duplicates of.

[image: screenshot of sort order of posts with the dropdown menu visible and "frequent" circled]

The one downside of this sort is that it's all-time, so it doesn't indicate what's recently being accessed.

How big your Team is may change the experience of people using it - both people struggling with understanding issues and with people trying to address them. Voting is an important aspect and getting people to remember to vote is something that we've struggled with on our public sites, too - so you're not alone.

Often, it's cultural to the site - some sites have tons of voting and lots of people who are there sharing their feelings about the content. On other sites, even ones with lots of people, there's not a lot of voting at all. That could be for a wide variety of reasons, and understanding why is the first step in understanding how to get people to vote more.

Sometimes that means helping people understand the value of voting and the signal it sends. It can take some effort on your part to encourage people to vote - if your Team is used to using passive resources like a wiki or forum where voting isn't an option, they may need reminders that the voting feature is there for them to use.

Comment: I wasn't aware that `frequent` did meant `most view`. I did try the filter and for me it shows "No questions found. Perhaps you'd like to select a different tab?". is it a bug then?

Comment: I thought frequent was highest duplicate target count (as in, ordered by how many posts use that as a dupe target), not most viewed

Comment: Hmmm. This seems to be the case... that said, it may actually be a good indicator of what @RaphaëlBalet is looking for anyway.

Comment: Yes, often the two go hand in hand, most frequent (literally the most asked by duplicate count) would after all have some correlation with views

Comment: @Catija I did develop a bit my though an Idea in the description under `Explained use case`. I understand the use of `most frequent` even if it isn't working for the moment. But I'm not sure it satisfy my needs, because of the "Sales & support" use case. What do you think?

Comment: @RaphaëlBalet It's not about *forcing* them to vote, though - it's about helping them see the value in voting - "We'd really love to know which issues are most important to you as you work with clients because we want to prioritize these, so there are a few ways that you can help us identify these - one way is to vote on the posts so that we see that they're important to you. Another way is to leave a comment if you have a customer run into this problem. We want to make sure the product is useful, and that we're triaging improvements and bug fixes effectively"

Comment: Votes are anonymous, so you can't know who's casting them - comments in Teams situations can often work better in helping you identify who thinks an idea is useful. And if your sales/support team are hitting a roadblock multiple times, they can only vote once, so having them leave a comment citing each specific case where a client has had this issue, you can count how many times it's come up and see how frequent the issue is.

Comment: @Catija I agree with you, and I can explain to the team what you just said and they will understand. It was just a feature request about a feature that I don't think really exists in stack overflow and could help people like me who want more data to work with. As far as feedback goes, the team will come directly to me, not asking directly on stack, but through another channel _Microsoft Teams_. And I don't want to force them to use stack overflow. I just want to know if this site is really being used as a reference for any questions that are not yet answered.